# Remove the Validation and Error message from Lightning-input field on Focus

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-design-system, html

I am using the Lightning-input field which is **required** field.

When I leave the field empty it shows a validation error. But the error stays there till I give some input and **click outside**

Is there any way to remove the validation error border and Error message as soon as I Focus Into the Input field?
[image]

Comment: I don't there is any standard way to resolve this. You may create HTML input fields instead of standard lightning field.

Comment: Yes..i know but that will complicate the other processes like Fields validations etc.

Answer (score 3):

In order to remove the error message and border as soon as an user fills the required field you can handle the keyup event calling the `reportValidity()` method on lightning-input element.
[Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input/specification) (emphasis mine):

> Displays the error messages and returns false if the input is invalid.
> **If the input is valid, reportValidity() clears displayed error messages and returns true**.

HTML:

```
<lightning-input required type="text" label="Enter some text" onkeyup={handleKeyUp}></lightning-input>
```

JS:

```
handleKeyUp(event) {
    event.currentTarget.reportValidity();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is a solution that uses a workaround. Please assess risks before using.

You'll need to remove the **slds-has-error** class explicitly using javascript.

There are 2 parts to this because removing the slds-has-error only removes the styles related to an error, not the elements related to it.

**1st** - Removing the red border and slds-has-error

HTML:

```
<lightning-input class="thisInput" type="text" label="Enter some text" onfocus={handleFocus} required ></lightning-input>
```

JS:

```
handleFocus(event) {
    event.target.className = event.target.className.replace('slds-has-error', '');
}
```

Using QuerySelector:

```
handleFocus(event) {
    let input = this.template.querySelector('.thisInput');
    input.className = input.className.replace('slds-has-error', '');
}
```

**2nd** - Removing the validation message from the view

You'll need to override the slds-form-element__help css only in the event that it doesn't have its corresponding slds-has-error. You can achieve that by importing a css file from the static resource (overriding inside your LWC will not allow this).

inputLwc.js:

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import override from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/override.css';

export default class InputLwc extends LightningElement {
    overrideCss = override;

    connectedCallback() {
        loadStyle(this, this.overrideCss)
        .then(() => {
            console.log('overrideCss loaded');
        });
    }
}
```

override.css:

```
.thisInput:not(.slds-has-error) .slds-form-element__help {
     display: none;
}
```